# special characters in MacVim

Tags: macvim

I added the Vim plugins and such from this page http://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles.
I followed the instructions on the page and it all worked out fine, except the part on getting Command-T to work. But that's okey, I'll just map CTRL-F instead...

The problem is that I no longer can write "@" or any of the special characters that is typed using "alt".

**alt-2** now writes **'²'** (raised 2).

Any ideas?

**Edit: **

I have tracked down the issue to the following

```
if has("gui_mac") || has("gui_macvim")
    set guifont=Menlo:h14
    " key binding for Command-T to behave properly
    " uncomment to replace the Mac Command-T key to Command-T plugin
    "macmenu &File.New\ Tab key=<nop>
    "map <D-t> :CommandT<CR>
    " make Mac's Option key behave as the Meta key
    set invmmta
    try
      set transparency=5
    catch
    endtry
endif
```

I uncommented those two lines in my attempts to get Command-T to work... Now the question is, how do you reverse it? Just commenting them again doesn't work.

Comment: the issue only occurs in macvim btw!

Comment: the issue also only occurs in macvim not in vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to comment-away the row with "set invmmta"